# Imagemagic - converting pdf file together with png results in negated colors

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have a png file and a pdf file with two pages and I'd like to create a third png file with the content of the 3 images one on top of the other.

Running the following commands creates the file as expected with the two pdf pages:

```bash
magick convert \
\( -density 300 -colorspace CMYK -resize 1024 -quality 90 input.pdf \) \
-resize 3299x -append \
output.png
```

However, when I try to add the png file on top:

```bash
magick convert \
input.png \
\( -density 300 -colorspace CMYK -resize 1024 -quality 90 input.pdf \) \
-resize 3299x -append \
output.png
```

The part of the image that corresponds to the `input.png` looks fine, but the part that corresponds to the `input.pdf` pages will have their colours negated.

Running the initial pdf convert and the append in two separate commands works as expected:

```bash
magick convert -density 300 -colorspace CMYK -resize 1024 -quality 90 input.pdf output_%d.png
magick convert input.png output_0.png output_1.png -resize 3299x -append result.png
```

But I will be running these through mini_magick and if possible I'd like to condense the calls to ImageMagick in order to keep the code base cleaner and not have to deal with intermediate files.

Comment: Imagemagick uses Ghostscript to read the PDF. But it does not handle CMYK and expects you to convert it to sRGB when reading. Note that for Imagemagick 7, use magick, not magick convert and not convert. PNG does not support CMYK. Change -colorspace CMYK to -colorspace sRGB

Comment: @fmw42 Changing the colorspace to sRGB results in an image with transparent background. Tried adding `-background white` but seemed to make no difference.
Sorry about the novice questions, but I have zero experience with imagemagick and ghostscript.
Convering earlier without the png file on top had the same problem of outputting a transparent background, but it was fixed when I added the CMYK colorspace. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Post your PDF and PNG files and I will look at your commands. Upload them to some free hosting service and put the links in a comment or your question.

Comment: @fmw42 The actual files I used for testing have private information but I was able to reproduce this behaviour with a dummy pdf I found on google and a png created with gimp. I created a repository with test files here: https://github.com/julian-berbel/imagemagick-pdf-inverted-colors-problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I downloaded your files and cannot read any of them.

Comment: That's odd? It's just a blank pdf that says "Dummy PDF File" and a blank png that says "Hello Stack Overflow!". I created them on MacOS but I'm able to open them on both windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: OK, I got them now.

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, the proper syntax is to read the input, then apply settings and operators following and then the output. So you need to move your quality and resize after the PDF is read. Also convert o sRGB since Ghostscript does not process CMYK properly. Then to avoid the transparency, add -alpha off at the end. So the following should do what you want.

```
magick \
input.png \
\( -density 300 -colorspace sRGB input.pdf \
-alpha off -resize 1024 -quality 90 \) \
-resize 3299x -append \
output.png
```